# Conversion between NVARCHAR to VARCHAR

Tags: oracle, utf-8, nvarchar

I've got an Oracle DB with ALL the character columns defined as NVARCHAR or NCHAR or NCLOB, using charset UTF-16.

Now I want to migrate to a new DB that has charset UTF-8. Since it can store unicode characters, I'm wandering if I will be able to import data converting column types.

The reason I'm doubtful is I know that I cannot convert a NVARCHAR2 column in a VARCHAR2 if not empty.

What is the best option to perform the import. Will datapump complain if I import the schema, modify the column types and after that I'll import the data?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Yes datapump would be unimpressed with your proposed solution. You need to use to_char() or cast( MYNVARCHAR2 as VARCHAR2 ) to convert the datatypes after the import or before the export. As far as I know, any characters which can't be converted will be turned into '?'s so you have to be careful not to convert any data that contains non-english-alphabet characters.

It will probably be easiest to just import the data as is into a different schema, then convert the data while copying it to the correct, modified schema. i.e.

> impdp remap_schema=myschema:tempschema
>
> insert into myschema.mytable (select myprimarykey, to_char(mynvarchar2) from tempschema.mytable);

But this will obviously use up twice the space in your database.